# Failing to correctly reference currently installed version of .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I created the project when I had RC2 installed. Then when .NET Core 1.0.0 was released, I uninstalled rc2 and installed 1.0.0. The app is not able to connect to the database now. Also the 'Update-Database' command in the Package Manager Console is not executing correctly. I changed all the dependencies in the project.lock.json from '1.0.0-rc2-3002702' to '1.0.0' but the same error occurs.

The error in the Package Manager Console:

> Receiving an error in PMC:
>    The specified framework 'Microsoft.NETCore.App', version '1.0.0-rc2-3002702' was not found. - Check application dependencies and target a framework version installed at:     C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App
>
> The following versions are installed: 1.0.0 Alternatively, install the framework version '1.0.0-rc2-3002702'.

I am wondering where else a reference to that version of .NET Core might be stated?

This is my project.json - http://pastebin.com/wC91swU7

Answer (score 0):

> I changed all the dependencies in the project.lock.json

1. You have edited wrong file. You should update dependencies versions in **project.json** file and then run package restore command - this will regenerate project.lock.json.
2. Recheck your dependency list. At least I see the following problems

   - tools should be updated from 1.0.0-preview1-final to 1.0.0-preview2-final
   - "Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework"  is now Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore
   - why you use Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin ? Maybe you need Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity?

Comment: Thanks but there are no dependencies in project.json to '1.0.0-rc2-3002702'. Nothing is found in the solution that is referencing '1.0.0-rc2-3002702'.

Comment: show your project.json. Seems like one of your dependency has own dependency on rc2 package

Comment: pastebin.com/wC91swU7 Probably the Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.Core

Comment: have updated answer, and add project.json to question

Comment: I updated tools to preview2, removed owin and entityframework and now the only underlined problem packages are "Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Common": "1.3.0" and "Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp": "1.3.0". It says they expected '1.3.0-beta1-20160429-01' but received '1.3.0'.

Comment: again, this is cause one of the other packages uses the "beta" version... post your updated project.json

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found was installing:

PM> Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools -Pre

and replace preview1 with preview2 in